# How can I make a property to be available (non-Null) inside a method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, parse-platform, properties

I have this property defined

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *ObjectID;
```

And this is my ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PFQuery *getObjectIDforRow = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Event"];
    [getObjectIDforRow selectKeys:@[@"objectId"]]; // We decide which fields to get
    [getObjectIDforRow whereKey:@"Organizator" notEqualTo:PFUser.currentUser.username];
    [getObjectIDforRow whereKey:@"EventLocation" equalTo:Pointfrommap];

    // This method is to get the ObjectID for the selected row
    [getObjectIDforRow findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // We save the Object ID found in a NSString
            self.ObjectID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [objects valueForKey:@"objectId"]];

            NSLog(@"Object ID %@", self.ObjectID);

            [self getParticipantsarray]; // Here the exception won't come, but self.ObjectID is still null


        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];


}
```

And this is the getParticipantsarray:

```
-(void)getParticipantsarray{

    NSLog(@"Object ID is %@", self.ObjectID); // ID = Gj95aETEWq

     PFQuery *getArrayParticipants = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Event"];
    [getArrayParticipants selectKeys:@[@"Participants"]]; // We decide which fields to get

    [getArrayParticipants whereKey:@"ObjectId" equalTo:self.ObjectID]; // Here ObjectID is Null 
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

**My problem:**

For some reason I don't know, `ObjectID` hold a null value inside the `getArrayParticipants` `PFQuery` I created, whereas in the `viewDidLoad`, and event inside the method, holds the correct value.

**My guess:**

I think it has something to do with synchronous/async threads, as it was pointed before

Comment: You must be calling `getParticipantsArray` before the property has been set (possibly from somewhere else or you are creating another instance of the view controller somewhere).  Set a breakpoint in `getParticipantsArray` to identify the caller.

Comment: That is very logical :) but it still crashes because of the same exception I am afraid

Comment: I can't parse the posted code.  Did you leave out some?  Maybe where the PFQuery find is run?  I think what's happening is that you're setting the objectId property in the (async) completion block of a query, but testing it before that query completes.  Can you double check the code?  It couldn't compile as is

Comment: Ok, after your edit it makes more sense; You are setting `self.objectID` asynchronously.

Comment: Yeah I pasted the full viewdidload !

Comment: I remember something about a dispatch_sync. I am not sure if its about something related to that

Comment: You need to move the call to `[self getParticipantsarray];` to be inside the completion block where you set `self.ObjectID`.

Comment: In fact now I don't get the exception error, so seems to work fine

Comment: But I edited my question because now ObjectID in equalTo:self.ObjectID is null. I believe its again because this query is being performed asynchronously.